# Reposition of a google maps marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have several markers on a google map api v3 and i need to reposition the markers at regular intervals. I have given my markers specific names like markerA, markerB, ... markerO.

im trying to run this function to get access to right marker to reposition:

```
function moveMarker(marker,lat,lng) {
  var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
  marker.setPosition(newLatLng);
}
```

markers are created in the load process along with the map.

```
  markerA = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.870131, 10.819168), map: map, icon: rodIcon, title: 'Car A'});
  markerB = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.870131, 10.819168), map: map, icon: rodIcon, title: 'Car B'});
  markerC = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.870131, 10.819168), map: map, icon: blaIcon, title: 'Car C'});
```

however, it seems like my function fails, and doesnt recognize the marker "name" given in the "marker" input of the function.

input to the function is similar to:

```
moveMarker(markerA,60,10)
```

but the marker doesnt move at all...

Am i missing something seriously basic, or is my idea repositioning each single marker by its name not the way to go?

i mean, i can hardcode

markerA.setPosition
markerB.setPosition etc... but that seems to be overkill?

Comment: Use arrays for your markers.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.setPosition()` method. See http://jsfiddle.net/Ln2BM/1/ :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    var pos = this.getPosition();
    this.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat(), pos.lng() + 1)); 
});
```

If it doesn't work, then you must have made a different mistake. Quite suspicious sounds your sentence *"my function fails, and doesnt recognize the marker "name" given in the "marker" input of the function"*. You probably have something wrong in your function call.